# laravel table related to only two elements on another table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables: trips and cities.

A trip should be only between two cities. (from "city A" to "city B").

In trips table, I put 2 foreign keys (city_A and city_B) referencing to "id" of cities table.

I dont know how to design this in laravel to get an optimised code.
I want to know what kind of relationship to use (hasOne or belongsToMany), and how can I retreive cities informations from tripController.

Comment: it is a manytomany relationship as a city can be part of many trips and trips can have multiple cities so make a pivot table which will have 2 columns city id and trip id and use this table to join the queries.

Comment: public function getCityA(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\City','city_trip',
                                    'trip_id','city_A')
                    ->withPivot('city_B');
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `belongsToMany()` (many to many) with extra pivot columns here. [`withPivot()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) method will help you.

You may want to read about [querying relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) and [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).